# change the link color

Tags: jquery, css

If i have 5 links.When first if i click a link it has to change to some other color and next if i click other link previous link color should go to default and this link color has to change

CODE:

```
$("table#menu tr > td a[href^='#']").click(function() { 
     $(this).toggleClass('class1'); / 
}); 

a.class1 { color:#000000; } 

<table id="menu"> 
<tr> 
   <td><a href="#" id="link1">qwerty</a></td> 
</tr> <tr> 
   <td><a href="#" id="link1">zyz</a></td> 
</tr> 
</table>
```

Comment: you'll have to do it manually by wiring up click events. if you can show ur your markup and requirements we'll be better able to help

Comment: @nEEbz:$("table#menu tr > td a[href^='#']").click(function() 
{
    
   
   $(this).toggleClass('class1');
   /
});    a.class1
{
    color:#000000;
}    <table id="menu">
    <tr>
        <td><a href="#" id="link1">qwerty</a></td>
        
</tr>
    <tr>
        <td><a href="#" id="link1">zyz</a></td>
    </tr>
</table>

Comment: After the call to toggleClass, there's a forward-slash `/`. Is it a typo?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should answer your question:

http://jsfiddle.net/TL9rh/

**html**

```
<div id="links">
    <a href="#">link1</a>
    <a href="#">link2</a>
    <a href="#">link3</a>
    <a href="#">link4</a>
    <a href="#">link5</a>
</div>
```

**javascript**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#links a').click(function(){
        $(this).addClass('selected');
        $(this).siblings().removeClass('selected');
    });
})
```

**css**

```
a {
    color: darkgreen;   
}


.selected {
     color: red;   
}
```

Comment: if i have table and each td has link.How would i do it?

Comment: can you change your styles with adding some id bcoz global is making problem here.

Answer (score 6):

Classes.

css:

```
a {
    color: green;
}
a.special {
    color: orange;
}
```

javascript:

```
$('a').click(function(evt) {
    evt.preventDefault(); //don't follow link
    //remove the special class from all links which already have it
    $('a.special').removeClass('special');
    //add the special classs to the clicked link
    $(this).addClass('special');
}
```

Of course, you should change the selectors to suit your html.

Live example: http://jsfiddle.net/KHjDr/

Comment: +1 For using classes instead of directly changing the colour.

Answer (score 0):

If the page that contains your links does **not** refresh, you can do so with CSS only.

**HTML**

```
<a href="#">MyLink1</a>
<a href="#">MyLink2</a>
<a href="#">MyLink3</a>
```

**CSS**

```
a:link{color: blue;}
a:active{color: red;}
```

Answer (score 0):

The Correct Version Will Be For jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('.win a').click(function(){
    $('.win a:first-child').removeClass('focused');
    $(this).addClass('focused');

});
```

})

and The Html:

```
<li class="widget-title win"><a class="focused" href="#window1">Recent News</a></li>
<li class="widget-title win"><a href="#window2">Most Favorites</a></li>
<li class="widget-title win"><a  href="#window3">Top News</a></li>
```